# How to fix Style/MultipleComparison offense in Rubocop?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I keep getting this offense when I run rubocop:

> bin/main:70:6: C: Style/MultipleComparison: Avoid comparing a variable with multiple items in a conditional, use Array#include? instead.

my code:

```
if board1 == [1, 2, 3] || board1 == [4, 5, 6] || board1 == [7, 8, 9] ||
   board1 == [3, 5, 7] || board1 == [1, 5, 9] || board1 == [1, 4, 7] ||
   board1 == [2, 5, 8] || board1 == [3, 6, 9]
  board1.each { |state| board_states[state - 1] = 'X' }
  puts "#{player1} win"
  break
end
```

I'm new to ruby and coding in general. How do I refactor the above code to be more concise as recommended by rubocop?

Comment: this question is more appropriate in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The docs provide examples: [Style/MultipleComparison](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.0/cops_style.html#stylemultiplecomparison)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubocop recommends you refactor the `if` condition using `Array#include?`.

```rb
  states = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [3, 5, 7], [1, 5, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]

  if states.include?(board1)
    board1.each { |state| board_states[state - 1] = 'X' }
    puts "#{player1} win"
    break
  end
```